# Query a column with jsonb data meeting certain criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

## Problem

I have a table like this:

| product | tags (jsonb) |
| --- | --- |
| P001 | [{"name": "LX","active": true}, {"name": "TX","active": true}] |
| P002 | [{"name": "LX","active": true}] |

I am trying to query against this table to get a list of products with tags that are the same.

I found the following to be insufficient for my query since it will match all products with at least the tag I query for:

```sql
SELECT product
FROM product_table 
WHERE tags @> '[
    {"name": "LX","active": true}
]';
```

### Result

| product |
| --- |
| P001 |
| P002 |

So I need the match to be more exact without being so strict as to demand order of tag objects in the array. For example:

```sql
[
    {
        "name": "LX",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "name": "TX",
        "active": true
    }
]
-- Interpreted the same as
[
    {
        "name": "TX",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "name": "LX",
        "active": true
    }
]
```

### Desired Result

A list of products that match only the tags in the query.

### Resources

A list of the resources I am using to try and solve the problem.

- [9.16. JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)
- [How To Query a JSONB Array of Objects as a Recordset in PostgreSQL](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-query-a-json-array-of-objects-as-a-recordset-in-postgresql-a81acec9fbc5)
- [Working with a JSONB Array of Objects in PostgreSQL](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/working-with-a-jsonb-array-of-objects-in-postgresql-d2b7e7f4db87)

Comment: Discovery: When I flip the operator <@ to @> and visa versa, I get different behavior which may benefit me. I think the answer involves this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on the example you give, you can use simultaneous containment in both directions.

```
...WHERE tags <@ :whatever and tags @> :whatever
```

If you don't like repeating the arguments, you could make a custom function, or operator:

```
create function equal_but_for_order(jsonb,jsonb) returns boolean language sql as $$ 
    select $1 <@ $2 and $1 @> $2
$$;

create operator <@> (function = equal_but_for_order, leftarg = jsonb, rightarg=jsonb);

...WHERE tags <@> :whatever
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, did you see my latest comment above? What do you make of changing the direction per the postgres docs?

Comment: This did it! @jjanes I was close since I was looking at how I could use `AND` with alternating `@>` and `<@` operators.